# android media player: dealing with incoming phone calls and playing audio in the background

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player

I am fairly new to Android app development and I need some direction. 
I have written an app that plays mp3 files from the internet via the Android MediaPlayer either one at a time or from a playlist.

The user can play one mp3 at a time or queue up several mp3's, go to a playlist screen and hear each one after the other. 
I have a progress bar, start, stop, pause, and continue buttons on the screen that plays a single mp3. 
On the playlist screen there is no progress bar, but there are start, stop, pause, and continue buttons.

I want the following behavior but I am not sure how to implement it correctly:

- when an mp3 is playing and an incoming phone call is received, the mp3 is paused; when the user hangs up, the mp3 is resumed automatically
- when an mp3 is playing, and the user presses the phone's "home" button, the mp3 continues to play while the user is free to do other things (like check email for example);

Do I need to implement the media player as a service? 
Do I need a separate thread to run the media player?

I am doing neither at the moment.

Is there a good tutorial on this?

I have tried the following tutorial in a separate app that implements the media player as a service and it seems to do most of what I want but I haven't been able to figure out how to incorporate a "pause" and "continue" button. 
"ServicesDemo - Using Android Services": http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

As a followup question, are there canned media players that can be purchased or available as a free download that already have this functionality that can be included in my app?

I'm not posting any code here yet as this is more a general question, but will as a followup.

Thanks in advance, 
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need service for your media player, and how  to handle phone calls read about AUDIO_FOCUS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code To Stop and Resume Song  in between calling

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener=new PhoneStateListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) 
        {
            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING )
            {
                MP.Pause();
            }
           else if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK )
           {
           MP.Pause();

         }else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                MP.Start();
            }

        }

    };
    TelephonyManager manger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(manger!= null) {
        manger.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```